npmrc same scope multiple projects setup
I have a gitlab main folder where i have multiple repos so one scope and multiple projects...now there are two projects A and B where I have specified the name to be: @scope/A in project A's package.json and name to be: @scope/B in project B's package.json. Now I have specified both of these A and B as dependencies in another project so I have created a .npmrc file and wrote following code:
#consider this for project A
@scope:registry="https://gitlab.com/api/v4/packages/npm/"
//gitlab.com/api/v4/packages/npm/:_authToken=xyz
//gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/123/packages/npm/:_authToken=xyz

#consider this for project B
@scope:registry="https://gitlab.com/api/v4/packages/npm/"
//gitlab.com/api/v4/packages/npm/:_authToken=abc
//gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/345/packages/npm/:_authToken=abc

now the problem that is happening is if i am doing npm info for the project A then it is giving 404 but if i comment out the project B configuration from .npmrc file then npm info works for project A. I understand the problem is because there are multiple configurations for same scope so it is always giving the second one.
Now how should I fix this issue is my question?
Tried:

having a single registry level token -> cannot use since this does not exist and we don't want to have a registry level token
went through npm open issues and stackoverflow previous questions but no one seems to have this problem

